# Bypass HR to talk to a hiring manager

Tags: hiring-process, human-resources

I recently came across an online job posting for a position nearly identical to what I do now but at a competing university.  For various reasons I would like to move to that university so I wrote a cover letter specific to that position highlighting the very similar work I have done in my current position and former ones then applied online.  I have not heard back from them at all.

I believe the fact that I have limited formal education in my field and the job posting explicitly said a BS in computer science or a related field was required may mean the "first level" HR people (or software they use to sift through applicants) isn't bothering to consider me for that reason.  I had similar trouble getting hired where I currently work, the managers wanted to hire me and felt my skills were beyond what they needed but HR didn't want to let me be hired because I didn't meet the written requirements of the position (again, formal education).  What is the recommended way to move forward and ensure an actual human with basic knowledge of the job requirements reads my resume and cover letter?

Answer (score 4):

When I had a similar experience, albeit it was through a contracting firm and not academia HR, I ended up making several follow up phone calls to get some information as to why I was not considered.  When I found out it was because I didn't have the correct 'formal education', I detailed more of my specific experiences, indicating I was indeed qualified, and got an interview and a job.

Ideally your resume should speak for itself and you, but talking to someone on the phone gave me a chance to fight for the position.